# How to make half-circle on top of a rectangle such that it perfectly fits?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

First I make it in the center of the rectangle then I cut the half of it using direct selection tool but I get a picture like this and it doesn't fit perfectly.
So how to make it fit perfectly?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have Smart Guides switched on.

1. Begin clicking and dragging with the Ellipse Tool where it intersects with the top middle of the rectangle, and then without releasing the mouse button hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as you continue to click and drag.
2. Release the mouse button when the Smart Guide shows it is lined up with the edge of the rectangle.
3. Now use the Direct Selection Tool <kbd>A</kbd> to delete the bottom anchor.

Now you can zoom in to check everything is aligned.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Draw a circle
- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** to delete the bottom anchor
- Use the **Pen Tool** to connect to one anchor and draw a rectangle
- Select anchors with the **Direct Selection Tool** and then use buttons on the **Align Panel** to align the anchors

If you then need two separate shapes....

- Copy the art
- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** to select and **delete** the top anchor
- Join the two top remaining anchors (`Object > Path > Join`). There's your rectangle
- Align to circle shape

[image]

Or simply draw a circle, delete the bottom anchor and then join the two side anchors, forming the bottom path segment. Then draw rectangle the same width as the circle and use the align panel to align the half circle and the rectangle.

[image]